# Reinit xvfb resources

Tags: ubuntu, xvfb

I user xvfb on my Ubuntu servers mostly to run browsers in Selenium QA automation.
I user this servers to test web applications, so I run A LOT of browsers.
But after some time errors appears like

```
xvfb-run firefox
xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start
```

I tried

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum firefox
```

but got same error

I think there is some problem with initialization some resources, which use xvfb, because after server reboot xvfb works fine for some time.
So I want these resources reinitilized after this error, but I don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem
There is hanging process in system with name

```
Xvfb
```

I killed it and work fine. I newer found it earlier beacuse I used to try to find process with 'xvfb' name